# Using java.util.Scanner to print out Scheme Host and Path

Tags: java, uri, java.util.scanner

So I am supposed to Write a program that reads a URI, for example http://www.cs.unca.edu/csci202, contained on the first input line.
And if an exception is raised by the constructor, the program should print a message giving some information about that problem. And if no exception is raised, the program should print the scheme, host and path of the URI using the appropriate methods of the URI. And if any of these URI properties is missing, it should not be printed. I am supposed to use the scanner to be able to type in the URI and then have it print out the scheme Host Path or error message. So far nothing I have tried has worked. Here is what I have so far:

```java
import java.net.URI;

public class Home04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            URI uri1 = new URI("");

            if (uri1.getScheme() != null) {
                System.out.println("Sceme:" + uri1.getScheme() );
            }
            if (uri1.getHost() !=null){
                System.out.println("Host:" + uri1.getHost() );
            }
            if (uri1.getPath() != null){
                System.out.println("Path:" + uri1.getPath() );
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing code is correct.

What you need to do is use below to get input from user

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
URI uri1 = new URI(scanner.next());
```

Comment: It works now but for some reason after i added the scanner the exception stopped working. How do I get the exception to print out when there is a problem raised by the constructor